# How to add non-enumerable property in JavaScript for IE8?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, cross-browser, enumerable

Is there a way to add "hidden" non-enumerable properties to a JavaScript object that works cross-browser?

For most modern browsers, you can do:

```
Object.defineProperty(obj, '__id__', { enumerable: false, value: id++ });
```

For some older non-IE browsers that don't have `Object.defineProperty`, you can use [the `__proto__` hack](http://perfectionkills.com/how-ecmascript-5-still-does-not-allow-to-subclass-an-array/#wrappers_prototype_chain_injection).

None of those, however, work for IE. Is there a way to accomplish this in IE8 (would be cool if IE7 too, but not necessary)?

The main goal is to be able to add tracker properties to any JavaScript `{}` object, but such that when you call `JSON.stringify(obj)`, it doesn't get included in the property. I realize you can add custom JSON replacer functions (basically extending the `JSON.stringify` functionality), but I'm not a big fan of that because it means any time you serialized these tracked JavaScript Objects into JSON, you would have to know/remember to add that replacer function which is pretty impractical.

Is there any way to accomplish this?

Comment: You say IE8+, but doesn't `Object.defineProperty()` work in IE9?

Comment: Oh yeah, I guess I just mean IE8. If there's a way to support IE7 too that would be awesome, but basically just how to do it in IE8. Updated question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I cannot reproduce it in IE8 compatability mode in IE10 but
defining a property like `"toLocaleString"` should work because of [the don't enum bug in IE8](https://web.archive.org/web/20130221162022/https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/ECMAScript_DontEnum_attribute#JScript_DontEnum_Bug).

```
var uniqueId = function() {
    var dontEnumBug = false;
    var id = 0;

    if( !Object.defineProperty ) {
        var keyVisited = false;
        for( var k in {toLocaleString: 3}) {
            if( k === "toLocaleString" ) {
                keyVisited = true; 
            }
        }
        if( !keyVisited ) {
            dontEnumBug = true;
        }
    }

    return function( obj ) {
        if( dontEnumBug ) {
            obj.toLocaleString = id++;
        }
        else {
            Object.defineProperty(obj, '__id__', { enumerable: false, value: id++ });
        }

    }

})();
```

You could also use `"isPrototypeOf"` or `"propertyIsEnumerable"` as these are also functions that are pretty much never called.

Comment: @LancePollard I think there was a bug .. just don't use this code ok lol