# ES5/IE8 Set a property no-enumerable

Tags: javascript, properties, internet-explorer-8, ecmascript-5, enumerable

I use a library which adds some properties to Array class.
Example :

```
Array.prototype.realFunction = function(){return true;}
```

Those added properties are enumerable, thus it will cause some problems for loops (for...in) (code from MS :D).

So, I did some code to set those properties as no-enumerable but it doesn't work on IE8.

```
for(var p in Array.prototype) 
{ 
        var desc = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Array.prototype, p); 
        if(desc != null && desc.enumerable) { 
                desc.enumerable = false; 
                Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, p, desc); 
        } 
}
```

How can I do that?

Thanks for your help, i'm gonna die ;) !

Best regards

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add non-enumerable property in JavaScript for IE8?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17934888/how-to-add-non-enumerable-property-in-javascript-for-ie8)

Comment: It is not a duplicate.

Comment: How so? You're trying to make a non-enumerable property in IE8, right?

Comment: [Object.defineProperty compatability](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty#Browser_compatibility)